# slideshow of a collection of images managed with uicollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView (with horizontal layout) to manage a collection of images. The view controller that manages the collection view has the bottom toolbar visible with a play button to start a slideshow of the images in the collection. My question is what is the best way to implement a slideshow that involves a collection view? My initial thought was to try to make the collection view changing the visible cells with a UIView transition (transitionFromView or transitionWithView) with a cross dissolve option but I didn't get the effect I was expecting (maybe something wrong in my code). The other idea I had was to simply add a subview to the collection view to handle slideshow. This subview would have access to the data source and be able to iterate through the images. Don't know if this last option is a good way to approach the problem. Anyone has ever tried this and/or what would the recommendation be to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My idea is no need of collection view. In scrollview place imageview which display images. In timer Change the offset of scrollview. so it looks like automatically images are changing as like slide show.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use the uicollectionview for displaying the collection of images. Regarding the slideshow, it seems that you are more in favor of the second option: add a subview to the collection view to handle slideshow